# Unable to Access Jarfile Selenium Grid on CMD

Tags: java, selenium, cmd, selenium-grid

I'm trying to install Selenium Grid on my computer.

I tried Java SDK 8, 11, and 18 and none of them worked.

I created a file in C: driver and added a jar in this folder.

[image: photo1]

[image: photo2]

Comment: The Windows folder has special permissions.  I'd consider placing that in a user folder.

Comment: I replaced folder but stiill not worked. @pcalkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role hub
```

not working on Windows. Correct format is:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.2.2.jar standalone
```

But this is maybe still not work. We need to add "***ChromeDriver***" and define path. You need to store driver file in SeleniumGrid folder.
After that steps Hub is start working.

[image: grid]

Comment: For the complete documentation use this link. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/